# Why don't Asuka and Mari wear headsets?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

Shinji, Rei and other pilots wear these headsets:

[image]

But why don't Asuka and Mari wear those headsets?

Comment: I have never seen these yellow blobs, what is your source for this picture? The only other versions I can find don't have the head wear.

Comment: @mivilar: I think the yellow blobs are added to the picture to highlight the device on their head. For example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QqT3W.jpg

Comment: @nhahtdh Well I feel stupid now, thanks for clarifying ;)

Comment: @mivilar: I think your comment is valid, since I also thought that they are part of the original design until your comment makes me google about it.

Comment: Maybe they have a different shape from those of the other pilots? Mari uses a headband while Asuka uses two hairpins, maybe the headsets are built inside. The two "maybe" should make clear that I'm 100%  guessing.

Answer (score 13):

They wear them in a different place, and both of them also "accessorize" them:

Asuka wears red ones that double as hair clips:

[image]

And Mari wears white ones as part of her hair band:

[image]

Both of them are seen pretty much wearing them all the time.

Also, the [Interface Headset wiki page](https://wiki.evageeks.org/Interface_Headset) says:

> The headsets used by Asuka Langley Soryu, and by Asuka Shikinami Langley for her Eva-03 test, are both more similar to hair clips in form than the default model. Mari Makinami Illustrious also wears a unique model incorporated into a hairband. For both Asuka and Mari, the headset lies against different parts of the brain than the standard model, but whether this has any functional implications isn't known.

Comment: And why they wear her hair clips all time?

Comment: There isn't a specific reason given in the show, speculatively, maybe because Asuka is proud to be an Eva pilot. It's obvious both Asuka and Mari have their headsets integrated into their hairstyles so maybe they just like wearing their hair that way